# echo database variables after post form

Tags: php, jquery

I use a form within a page with jquery tabs, on all the tabs there are other forms so i submit the form without refreshing the page like this:

```
$(document).on("submit", "#advertentie_tab", function(event) {
/* stop form from submitting normally */    
    event.preventDefault();      
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"advertentie.php",
        cache: false,                   
        data: $("#advertentie_tab").serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            $("#innertab_advertentie").html(data);
        }       
    });
});
```

In my form I echo some data from the database, but after the post i lose this data. Is there a way to keep the data after the post without setting a lot of hidden inputs?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what your problem really is, but i think you could always get your form data with jquery and before post save them to variables, therefore you have your lost data in js variables.

Answer (score 0):

The question you're stating is a bit awkward.

You could try writing the array of postdata to the session in that advertentie.php.. but that's pretty ugly.

Also, remember to clean your session data after retrieving this postdata from the session.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using ajaxForm for passing my form without changing pages, I think it may work the way you want.

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/